# DAX Iterator Behavior

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerpivot, daxstudio

I don't think this is doing what I want it to do. I have a fact table with columns date, weekstarting, customer, product and qtyshipped and I want an average product sales including dates with 0 sales. The 0 sales dates don't exist in the table. If I use an iterator does this do what I think its doing? I've grouped by week.

AVERAGEX(VALUES(facttable[weekstarting]),SUM(fact[qtyshipped]))

If this doesn't work this way is there a way to make a measure that would account for these 0s without editing the fact table? I can't seem to find a function that would do this.

Comment: You want the average per day including all the dates without sales?

Comment: Yes, so if i happen to have 3 weeks with sales and 1 week without I want the denominator to be 4. But its only 3. I realize I can sort of get around this by hard coding / using a variable for the denominator but I also want to get stdev.p to work and that's harder to hard code with dax. I dug into it and the way I wrote this formula it definitely doesn't work but I don't know if I could write an averagex or other function that would work.

Answer (score 0):

It'd just bypass the average function and use a SUM and divide by DATEDIFF set to days, weeks or what ever you want the average of.

```
DIVIDE(
    SUM( fact[qtyshipped] ),
    DATEDIFF(
        facttable[weekstarting],
        facttable[weekending],
        WEEK
    )
)
```